# Создание const поля в объекте структуры

Tags: c++, c

Имеется поле в структуре с расширением const. Как заполнить его извне при создании обьекта (например, конструктор). Важно, чтоб поле было именно const

Answer (score 5):

Назначить значение полю `const` можно только при инициализации.

Любой синтаксис инициализации это будет делать без проблем. В том числе в С++  - синтаксис инициализации в списке инициализации конструктора.

Заполняем извне при создании объекта

```
struct S { const int i; };

struct S s1 = { 42 };
struct S s2 = { 123 };
```

или

```
struct S 
{ 
  const int i; 

  S(int i) : i(i)
    {}
};

S s(42);
```

и т.д.

То есть никаких особенностей в инициализации const-полей нет. Все как обычно.